# Is it ok to have a property decorated method to return a class in Python?

Tags: python

Let's say I have the following code:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param = param

    @property
    def super_param(self):
        return Param(self, self.param)


class Param(object):
    def __init__(self, parent, param):
        self.param = param
        self.parent = parent

    @property
    def get_parent(self):
        return self.parent
```

My question is, is it considered bad practice to use the @property decorator in this way? Are there any pros or cons?

Comment: Your method returns not a class, but instance. And new instance will be returned every time. Strange behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param = Param(self, param)
```

I don't think there's anything particularly wrong with returning a class from a property; a better question is, what are you trying to accomplish by doing so?

**Edit:** if you don't want it changed, make it a private property:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, param):
        self._param = param     # naming convention, 'don't muck with it'
        # OR
        self.__param = param    # name mangled

    @property
    def param(self):
        return self._param
```

Comment: Well, maybe I'm paranoid, but I want to avoid having the user set the param attribute to another value once the class has been instantiated

Comment: You should probably use `self.__param = param` instead of `self._param = param`, if you want to hide it more from the users. The name will be then mangled and from outside the class will be accessible as `some_object._MyClass__param`, while as `self.__param` from within the class.

Comment: It was better as `self._param`. Name mangling isn't for this kind of "private" attribute, its for avoiding name clashes with subclasses (which is only rarely an issue). @PingPengũin Python convention is that a single leading underscore makes an attribute an implementation detail, and not part of any guarantees you make about class invariants or even whether it will stick around in later versions. Sure, your users can play with it, but anything that goes wrong if they do is their own fault.

Comment: I second @lvc and PEP-8 [somewhat agrees with it too](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles). Actually, these schemes for "privateering" stuff are usually frowned upon among various Pythonistas. It is upon to you to use them, of course, but I think it is good to know that some/many find this annoyingly uptight and unpythonic. Also, [this classic text](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html) touches the point we're discussing.